# nginx video streaming statistics

Tags: nginx, video-streaming

I am using ngx_http_mp4_module to stream videos from my server. I have a server that can be accessed by multiple domains.

I used the following to configure nginx:

```
location /content/ {
    mp4;
    mp4_buffer_size       1m;
    mp4_max_buffer_size   5m;
}
```

I store all the videos under /content folder in my server and access them via url: http://example.com/content/testvideo.mp4

Since I can access my server with multiple domains, I can watch same video by visiting

> http://mydomain1.com/content/testvideo.mp4

or

> http://mydomain2.com/content/testvideo.mp4

Question is: how can I log statistics on which url a video has been watched and for how many seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a logging format which includes the `$host` and `$request_time` variables.

Use that logging format within that location directive.

Its fully documented on the Nginx website along with a list of variables available for including in the logs, the following belongs in the http block and is a modified version of the standard `combined` log format with the two variables above added to the end:

`log_format streaming '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $host $request_time';`

This defines a log format with the name `streaming` , the variable `$host` is obviously the host name from the client request. `$request_time` is, according to the docs:

> request processing time in seconds with a milliseconds resolution;
>   time elapsed between the first bytes were read from the client and the
>   log write after the last bytes were sent to the client

If your video is CBR you could also use `$bytes_sent` to log the total data transmitted to the client and calculate the duration of video transmitted that way.

Once you have defined your custom log format then in your location block for the streaming you set a directive for requests to that location to use that format for logging, like this:

`access_log /path/to/log/video.log streaming;`

Which is just the path to write the log to, and `streaming` is the log format to use for this log.

Now Nginx will create a single log file containing all requests to this location, regardless of the domain the client visited.

Maybe you would prefer individual logs for each domain? No problem, just use the `$host` variable as part of the path in your `access_log` directive

`access_log /path/to/log/$host-video.log streaming;`

Now each domain will get its own log. example.com-video.log, example.net-video.log etc

Maybe you want both? No problem, you can specify multiple `access_log` directives within the same level:

```
access_log /path/to/log/video.log streaming;
access_log /path/to/log/$host-video.log streaming;
```